# Transaction check error when installing Sun JDK 7

Tags: linux, java, java-7

One my linux instance, I am trying to install JDK 7 using the rpm. There is already JRE 6 installed, and I want to install JDK 7 along that. When I try to install JDK 7, getting the following error:

```
# rpm -ivh jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm
  Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.7.0_03-fcs.x86_64 conflicts with file from package jre-1.6.0_20-fcs.x86_64
```

I also tried installing using yum using:

```
# yum install jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm
```

This resulted in Transaction check error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
    file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.7.0_03-fcs.x86_64 conflicts with file from package jre-1.6.0_20-fcs.x86_64
```

Can someone help me to get this installed. I HAVE to retain already installed JRE 6, so removing that is not the solution for me.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Noman A.

Comment: A minor note: If you prefix your code with a hash-sign, the code formatter will treat it as a comment, and not interpret it as a (root) shell prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find any solution to this, so I went ahead and installed JDK using the tar file available for the respective JDK version.

-Noman A.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem when using YUM.

The key is to use rpm followed by the --force flag, i.e. you first install the JRE 1.6 (which you have already) and then issue an rpm command like this

```
rpm -ivh jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm --force
```

It then installs the newer JDK not minding any error.

The file */etc/init.d/jexec* is exactly the same between both java versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Hopefully will be using it in future!