# Can't install jdk on Fedora with yum nor with rpm

Tags: centos, fedora, yum, java

Help! I can't figure out how to install a jdk!

```
[/usr/lib/jvm]$ su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

[/usr/lib/jvm]$ su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package java-1.7.0-openjdk available.
Error: Nothing to do

[/usr/lib/jvm]$ su -c "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

[/usr/lib/jvm]$ su -c "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package java-1.6.0-openjdk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Here I've manually downloaded some rpm's, the last one from oracle's website:

```
[~]$ rpm -ivh java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    java-1.7.0-openjdk = 1:1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20 is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1:1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20.x86_64


[~]$ sudo rpm -ivh java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20.x86_64.rpm 
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 from install of java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20.x86_64 conflicts with file from package java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.9-2.3.7.0.fc18.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 from install of java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.19-2.3.9.3.fc20.x86_64 conflicts with file from package java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.9-2.3.7.0.fc18.x86_64


[~]$ sudo rpm -ivh jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm 
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.7.0_21-fcs.x86_64 conflicts with file from package jdk-2000:1.6.0_38-fcs.x86_64
```

### Debug

Here's some debug information:

```
[/usr/lib/jvm]$ yum search jdk
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
=========================================================== N/S Matched: jdk ============================================================
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
jdk.x86_64 : Java(TM) Platform Standard Edition Development Kit
ldapjdk.noarch : The Mozilla LDAP Java SDK
Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

.

```
[/usr/lib/jvm]$ yum list java*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
java-1.5.0-gcj.x86_64
```

.

```
[/usr/lib/jvm]$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
```

### Requirements

I *must* have "**jni.h**", "**libjava.so**", "**libhpi.so**", "**lipverify.so**" and "**libjvm.so**" included.

So far I've found out that these DO NOT have what I need:

- Undesired Versions (for sure):

  - jdk1.7.0_06 <-- *I'm surprised about this one, but it doesn't have libjvm nor libhpi*
  - java-1.7.0
  - java-openjdk
  - java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64
  - java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4
  - java-1.6.0-openjdk
  - java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
  - jre-1.5.0-gcj
  - jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
  - jre-openjdk
  - jre-1.7.0
  - jre-7u11-linux-x64.rpm java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0
  - jre-1.5.0
  - jre1.7.0_11
  - jre-gcj

And these do:

- Desired Versions (that I know of, there could be more):

  - **jdk1.6.0_34-x86**
  - jdk1.5.0_22-x86
  - java-6-openjdk

Can someone help me install jdk1.6 or java-6-openjdk please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot use the Oracle rpm to install JDK 7 when you already have the Oracle JDK 6 as it tries to install the `/etc/init.d/jexec` script which is already installed and required for JDK 6.

I would advise sticking to the tarball or self extracting `*.bin` and using JAVA_HOME if you are going to use the Oracle distribution as it does not have this problem and you will probably not need [jexec](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6211008) anyway.

Comment: This is the right answer for those who do not want to be limited to one version being installed.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would suggest that you install the Oracle JDK not the OpenJDK. Otherwise you might risk running into some issues. I always found problems of all sorts and sizes with OpenJDK that I don't even bother trying it any more.

Download the JDK RPM from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and follow the usual instructions. Its usually very straightforward and without problems.

Full detailed instructions including how to install it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html).

Make sure you choose the right version you need (JDK 1.7 or JDK 1.6, dont mix) because from your question you seem to have a confusion of library versions from 1.5 to 1.7.

And another thing, uninstall whatever you have installed already before installing a fresh one to avoid conflicts.

Comment: In my question I stated that I downloaded "jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm" from Oracle's website, tried to install it, and it said something about it conflicting... However, I was able to download and install jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin from Oracles website, so I guess the lower version worked! Thanks

Comment: I presume there was something residual from the previous openjdk versions, which might have been the reason for the conflict (thats why I said uninstall whatever you have to install on a clean system). Glad you managed with JDK1.6

Comment: Note that my answer here is now outdated and only valid within the context of JDK 1.7. From JDK 11 onwards, using OpenJDK is the way to go, unless you want to go in production with licensed support from Oracle, in which case using the Oracle JDK might make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer here [Transaction check error when installing Sun JDK 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270380/transaction-check-error-when-installing-sun-jdk-7/18621115)

Basically you may use rpm --force to install one JDK on top of the other. This scenario is completely valid specially when you have to develop for different JAVA versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue.  I was not comfortable using --force command; did not want to risk messing-up the existing Java that came installed at system setup.

I ended up doing the following and running the app server with a different version of Java under a different user ID.

downloaded the Java tar.gz version and uncompressed:

```
tar -zxvf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.gz
```

Created the directory:

```
mkdir /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45
```

Copied the contents to the new directory manually:

```
cp -r /.../jdk1.7.0_45/* /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45
```

Set the java_home under the user ID home directory in .bashrc and .bash_profile files:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/lib/gcc:/usr/sfw/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo rpm -i jdk-11.0.9_linux-x64_bin.rpm
or whatever package you are trying to install