# Cannot install JDK 1.7 on Fedora 14

Tags: java, conflict

I am trying to install the latest version of JDK 1.7 on my Fedora 14 32 bit machine. I went to the Oracle website and downloaded the RPM http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and downloaded the RPM from there, after downloaded has finished I double clicked the rpm file to install, but the installation suddenly stops with this error.

Test Transaction Errors:   file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.7.0_51         fcs.i586 conflicts with file from package jre-1.6.0_22-fcs.i586

I checked in /usr/java directory and I see that I have JRE version 1.7 already installed. in fact when I run the java -version command this is what I get

```
[milli@milli ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

I dont know whther I have to delete /usr/java folder entirely and then try installing JDK 1.7. I tried moving the /usr/java file to an external disk, then I tried installed the JDK RPM, still I get the same error.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: And specifically read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18783765/139985

Answer (score 0):

I am CentOS user not Fedora, but I think that you can install JDK 1.7 regarding this installation procedure. I was installed JDK on this way and it should be the same for Fedora 20/19/18/17/16/15/14/13/12, CentOS 6.5/6.4/6.3/6.2/6.1/6/5.10, Red Hat (RHEL) 6.5/6.4/6.3/6.2/6.1/6/5.10.

Try it, here is a [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).

I hope that helps.

Comment: When I run the command to install, I am getting a conflict error with an older version of JRE, and the installation exits:     `[root@milli Downloads]# rpm -Uvh jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-2000:1.7.0_51-fcs.i586 conflicts with file from package jre-1.6.0_22-fcs.i586
[root@milli Downloads]# 
` What does this mean? Should I delete the older version of JRE 1.6? If so, how does one do that?